# Improving the speed of a for loop in Julia

Tags: julia

Here is my code in Julia platform and I like to speed it up. Is there anyway that I can make this faster? It takes 0.5 seconds for a dataset of 50k*50k. I was expecting Julia to be a lot faster than this or I am not sure if I am doing a silly implementation.

```
ar = [[1,2,3,4,5], [2,3,4,5,6,7,8], [4,7,8,9], [9,10], [2,3,4,5]]

SV = rand(10,5)

function h_score_0(ar ,SV)
    m = length(ar)
    SC = Array{Float64,2}(undef, size(SV, 2), m)
    for iter = 1:m
        nodes = ar[iter]
        for jj = 1:size(SV, 2)
            mx = maximum(SV[nodes, jj])
            mn = minimum(SV[nodes, jj])
            term1 = (mx - mn)^2;
            SC[jj, iter] = (term1);
        end
    end
    return score = sum(SC, dims = 1)
end
```

Comment: What are `ar` and `SV`?  do you have an implimentation in another language that's faster, or is it what you expect the speed should be?

Comment: If you hope for the best possible response to your question, ideally you would include code for generating sensible simulated values for `ar` and `SV`. Also it would be good to know how you are timing the routine (ie show the code).

Comment: I just edited the post and added ar and SV. Now the code can be understood a lot better and it actually can generate the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have some unnecessary allocations in your code:

```
mx = maximum(SV[nodes, jj])
mn = minimum(SV[nodes, jj])
```

Slices allocate, so each line makes a copy of the data here, you're actually copying the data *twice*, once on each line. You can either make sure to copy only once, or even better: use `view`, so there is no copy at all (note that `view` is much faster on Julia v1.5, in case you are using an older version).

```
SC = Array{Float64,2}(undef, size(SV, 2), m)
```

And no reason to create a matrix here, and sum over it afterwards, just accumulate while you are iterating:

```
score[i] += (mx - mn)^2
```

Here's a function that is >5x as fast on my laptop for the input data you specified:

```
function h_score_1(ar, SV)
    score = zeros(eltype(SV), length(ar))
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(ar)
        nodes = ar[i]
        for j in axes(SV, 2)
            SVview = view(SV, nodes, j)
            mx = maximum(SVview)
            mn = minimum(SVview)
            score[i] += (mx - mn)^2
        end
    end
    return score
end
```

This function outputs a one-dimensional vector instead of a 1xN matrix in your original function.

In principle, this could be even faster if we replace

```
mx = maximum(SVview)
mn = minimum(SVview)
```

with

```
(mn, mx) = extrema(SVview)
```

which only traverses the vector once, instead of twice. Unfortunately, there is a performance issue with `extrema`, so it is currently not as fast as separate `maximum/minimum` calls: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/31442

Finally, for absolutely getting the best performance at the cost of brevity, we can avoid creating a view at all and turn the calls to `maximum` and `minimum` into a single explicit loop traversal:

```
function h_score_2(ar, SV)
    score = zeros(eltype(SV), length(ar))
    @inbounds for i in eachindex(ar)
        nodes = ar[i]
        for j in axes(SV, 2)
            mx, mn = -Inf, +Inf
            for node in nodes
                x = SV[node, j]
                mx = ifelse(x > mx, x, mx)
                mn = ifelse(x < mn, x, mn)
            end
            score[i] += (mx - mn)^2
        end
    end
    return score
end
```

This also avoids the performance issue that `extrema` suffers, and looks up the `SV` element once per node. Although this version is annoying to write, it's substantially faster, even on Julia 1.5 where views are free. Here are some benchmark timings with your test data:

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime h_score_0($ar, $SV)
  2.344 μs (52 allocations: 6.19 KiB)
1×5 Matrix{Float64}:
 1.95458  2.94592  2.79438  0.709745  1.85877

julia> @btime h_score_1($ar, $SV)
  392.035 ns (1 allocation: 128 bytes)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.9545848011260765
 2.9459235098820167
 2.794383144368953
 0.7097448590904598
 1.8587691646610984

julia> @btime h_score_2($ar, $SV)
  118.243 ns (1 allocation: 128 bytes)
5-element Vector{Float64}:
 1.9545848011260765
 2.9459235098820167
 2.794383144368953
 0.7097448590904598
 1.8587691646610984
```

So explicitly writing out the innermost loop is worth it here, reducing time by another 3x or so. It's annoying that the Julia compiler isn't yet able to generate code this efficient, but it does get smarter with every version. On the other hand, the explicit loop version will be fast forever, so if this code is really performance critical, it's probably worth writing it out like this.

Comment: Thank you! I also get 5x speed up with a much larger dataset. Do you have any other idea that I can make this faster?

Comment: I considered multithreading, but a brief experiment yielded underwhelming results.

Comment: Instead of the view, you could use an explicit loop over `SV`. If you're using a Julia ≤ 1.4 then views are heap allocated, which can add up and/or reduce optimization opportunities. You could also use `extrema` to compute both the min and the max in a single pass over the data.

Comment: I edited this answer to add a version where the max/min computation is done with an explicit loop, which is significantly faster.

Comment: In my laptop I get better performance using h_score_1. It's almost 2x faster. Any thought?